# ToolTip Stay displayed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

In C#, how can I make a ToolTip remain displayed until the mouse move out of the ToolTip region. No matter what delay I set it stay displayed.

I tried to change AutoPopDelay, InitialDelay, and ReshowDelay properties to 0 but the only way I can see is to set the delay to a very large value which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible.  The native Windows control has hard-coded behavior to make the tip disappear when it has been shown long enough.  There's no way to override that behavior.

A tooltip that is permanent is a Label.

Comment: I don't need a "Permanent" Tooltip, just a tooltip that remains as long as the mouse is stationary. And over top of that, if I change the AutoPopDelay for let say 50 sec. it disapear after 5 sec. any way because of the AutomaticDelay property. Is there a way then to manualy set the delay to one or 2 min without changeging the InitialDelay, and ReshowDelay properties and AutomaticDelay as well?

Comment: It will silently ignore your AutoPopDelay value if you set it any higher than 32767.  Thirty two seconds is the most you can get out of it.  Make sure your tip text is short enough, or clear enough, to allow a user to comprehend it within that time span.  Five seconds is ideal.

Comment: Ok, so in clear, if the ToolTip object doesn't do what I want/need. I should create my own.

Answer (score 0):

ToolTip.StopTimer Method can be used to prevent the ToolTip from disappearing after n  seconds.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.stoptimer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

J.B, you can write an attached behavior (e.g: similar to the .Net ToolTipService class) and then you have a full control of when to show hide the tool tip as a matter of focus. 
However, I think you can still get that with the ToolTipService.ShowDuration and setting it int.Max (that would be something like 20 days...)

Comment: This is not a WPF app.